# How can I plot a big 3D surface (10 000 x 10 000 points)?

Tags: qt, opengl, plot

I have a surface given as `r[i, j]`, `phi[i, j]`, and `theta[i, j]` (height map in spherical coordinate system).

It's rather big: about 10K in x 10K points.

I know that it can be easily plotted as a 2D colormap image (for example, in PyQtGraph), but I want to somehow plot it as a surface (to demonstrate the effect of round earth).

Haven't someone already plot such big surfaces? And how did you cope with them?

Comment: 100M points is a large number indeed. Are you sure you actually need this level of precision, and why?

Comment: Well, AFAIK, some 3D engines can omit excessive points? Full precision is needed only when a region is zoomed in, not on the entire surface.

Comment: Yes. But building LODs is a task that is hardly suitable for runtime.

Comment: If you drop the resolution back a smidge you could do a single 8192^2 texture and splat the result on a sphere.  Or multiple 4096^2 textures.

Comment: Well, it's not the full sphere, but only a region on it. Also, I need to show 3D relief when zooming in...

Answer (score 2):

LoD is something that you have to implement. For elevation data it's easy enough; quadtrees are a perfect match for this task and you can use high quality filter kernels. Since refinement in a quadtree follows a geometric series the total memory requirements converge to 2× the original dataset.

There are a few caveats when triangulating sphere: You'll always end up with poles or discontinuities; when using spherical coordinates you have two poles where differential surface elements degenerate, which is something you'd rather want to avoid.

A much better approach is to represent the sphere as a mapping based on the 6 sides of a cube; i.e. assume the faces of a cube subdivided to a desired resolution and each vertex of that mesh projected onto the surface of the base sphere. A nice side effect of doing this is, that you can in fact store your heightmap data in a cubemap texture image, complete with filtered LoD levels. In the vertex shader you can then sample the data to displace the mesh.

Mesh LoD can be implemented in a number of ways. But here's an interesting suggestion: Start with a grid in screen space which you project onto the sphere you want to sample. That way you'll generate vertices for exactly just the part of the sphere that's actually going to be visible; add a little bit of margin for good measure, since you're going to displace vertices. Above the horizon vertices will miss the sphere; it's easy enough to clip these vertices to exactly the horizon (finding the root of a quadratic equation). You can do all of this in the vertex shader, and season it with tesselation shading to refine the grid where applicable.

A note on your 10k×10k mesh resolution. Unless you're going to display it on a display with at least 20k×20k pixels the limited display resolution would actually subsample the mesh resulting in frequency aliasing (see Nyquist theorem).